# Get users by user role and subsidiary ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-identity

In ASP.NET Identity we have following tables

- `AspNetUsers`
- `AspNetRoles`
- `AspNetUserRoles`

Additionally I added the following column to the `AspNetUsers` table

- `Subsidiary_ID`

Now I want to load a `list` with following filters

- RoleName == "Approver"
- Subsidiary_ID == "04"

So for that purpose I'm trying to write query like below

```
List<AspNetUser> approverprofiles = db.AspNetUsers.Where(w => w.Subsidary_ID == "04").Where(w => w.Name == "Approver").ToList();
```

but then I'm getting this error

> 'AspNetUser' does not contain a definition for 'Name' and no extension
>   method 'Name'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for roleName in AspNetUsers table, that does not exist.
If you want to get the users that have Subsidiary_ID == "04" and they are in role with RoleName == "Approver" then you must query like this:

```
 List<AspNetUser> approverprofiles = db.AspNetUsers
    .Where(w => w.Subsidary_ID == "04" && w.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "Approver"))
    .ToList();
```